# How do I configure NLog in code in a .NET Core 3 web app to match the "Microsoft.*" logger name and no target?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

The example nlog.config from [Getting started with ASP.NET Core 3](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3) has a rule with no writeTo property:

```
<!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

<!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
<logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
```

The only overloads of `LoggingConfiguration.AddRule()` and `LoggingConfiguration.AddRuleForAllLevels()` with a final argument require a non-null target argument:

```
public void AddRule(LogLevel minLevel, LogLevel maxLevel, Target target, string loggerNamePattern, bool final);
public void AddRuleForAllLevels(Target target, string loggerNamePattern, bool final);
```

How do I emulate this configuration in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bit more hidden in the API. Sending `null` as target will result in a `ArgumentNullException` or `NullReferenceException`. So that won't work. In this case you could use the `NullTarget` (namespace `NLog.Targets`)

You could define the equivalent rule as follows:

```c
var blackhole = new NullTarget();
loggingConfiguration.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Info, blackhole, "Microsoft.*", true);
```